# Using ifelse with write.table

Tags: r

I'm writing a file using ifelse:

```
ifelse("out.csv" %in% list.files(),
       write.table(summary, "out.csv", sep=",", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE),
       write.table(summary, "out.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
)
```

It seems to work fine but throws up an error: replacement has length zero

Any risk to using this code or a better way to do things?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the help, `ifelse` evaluates *both* the true and false arguments regardless of the value of the condition. What you want is a plain `if`.

```
if("out.csv" %in% list.files()) {
   write.table(summary, "out.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE,
       col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
} else {
   write.table(summary, "out.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I hadn't spotted that in help